# Openshift 4.4 problem with bootstrap complete

Tags: openshift, openshift-enterprise

I'm trying to install Openshift 4.4 on the vSphere platform. I set DHCP, DNS records and HAPROXY according to the documentation below :

[https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.4/installing/installing_vsphere/installing-vsphere.html](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.4/installing/installing_vsphere/installing-vsphere-network-customizations.html)

However when I get to the steps: **openshift-install wait-for bootstrap-complete --log-level debug**, the following error is shown to me.

[Following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCVjp.png)

Has anyone encountered this problem so far?

I am also setting up a haproxy server configuration:

```html
defaults
mode http
log global
option httplog
option dontlognull
option http-server-close
option forwardfor except 127.0.0.0/8
option redispatch
retries 3
timeout http-request 10s
timeout queue 1m
timeout connect 10s
timeout client 1m
timeout server 1m
timeout http-keep-alive 10s
timeout check 10s
maxconn 3000

frontend openshift-api-server
    bind 172.25.130.56:6443
    default_backend openshift-api-server
    mode tcp
    option tcplog

backend openshift-api-server
    balance source
    mode tcp
    server bootstrap 172.25.130.50:6443 check
    server ctrl-pln1 172.25.130.51:6443 check
    server ctrl-pln2 172.25.130.52:6443 check
    server ctrl-pln3 172.25.130.53:6443 check

frontend machine-config-server
    bind 172.25.130.56:22623
    default_backend machine-config-server
    mode tcp
    option tcplog

backend machine-config-server
    balance source
    mode tcp
    server bootstrap 172.25.130.50:22623 check
    server ctrl-pln1 172.25.130.51:22623 check
    server ctrl-pln2 172.25.130.52:22623 check
    server ctrl-pln3 172.25.130.53:22623 check

frontend ingress-http
    bind 172.25.130.56:8080
    default_backend ingress-http
    mode tcp
    option tcplog

backend ingress-http
    balance source
    mode tcp
    server compute1 172.25.130.54:8080 check
    server compute2 172.25.130.55:8080 check

frontend ingress-https
    bind 172.25.130.56:443
    default_backend ingress-https
    mode tcp
    option tcplog

backend ingress-https 
    balance source
    mode tcp
    server compute1 172.25.130.54:443 check
    server compute2 172.25.130.55:443 check
```

Comment: Once how about you compare your dns, haproxy config and so on with this article ? https://medium.com/@daein/ocp4-3-installation-on-rhv-4-3-with-bare-metal-method-653186c6de63

Comment: @carpel Maybe you have a typo somewhere, as your API URL seems to be `https//api...` (note the missing ":". Can you check your install-config?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your logs, it seems there is a missing `":"` between `"https"` and `"//api.os44..."` so this is not a valid url as the error messages says..